# Differential equations, theoretical question about lowering the power of a basic differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In the text book it says we can solve:(The area of existence and uniquesness of the equation is $G= R \times R^n$)$$x^{(n)}=f(t), f \in C(R) \tag{1}$$ the following method: Integrating (1) $n$ times getting: $$\int\int...\int f(t)dt...dt+ c_1t^{n-1}+...+c_{n-1}t+c_n.$$

The solution $x= \phi (t)$ which satisfies $\phi^{i}(t_0)=x^{i}_0, i=1..n-1, (t_0,x_0,x_0'...x_0^{(n-1)})\in G$ is

$$\phi(t)= \int_{t_0}^{t}... \int_{t_0}^{t}f(\epsilon)d \epsilon...d \epsilon + \frac{x_0^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}(t-t_0)^{n-1}...+\frac{x_0}{1!}'(t-t_0)$$ because

$$\int_{t_0}^{t}... \int_{t_0}^{t}f(\epsilon)d \epsilon... d \epsilon=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{t_0}^{t}f(\epsilon)(t- \epsilon)^{n-1}d \epsilon\tag{2}$$ so

$$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{t_0}^{t}f(\epsilon)(t- \epsilon)^{n-1}d \epsilon+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_0^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}(t-t_0)^{n-i}$$

Can anyone clarify why this is ? Why does this $\phi(t)$ satisfy and how is $(2)$ correct, what I am not seeing ?

Comment: You started the question with "It says...": who or what is "it"? Your equation (2) and the equation immediately before it doesn't make much sense as written (you are missing some integration elements), and it seems that you copied it from somewhere. It will help to know what are your sources.

Comment: The text book says this , i'll edit a few details now, that I see that.

Comment: I don't know what to do, I've got an exam on this in three days, and just don't understand some of the curriculum like this..

Comment: [The Cauchy formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) is what is used here, but you have dropped a number of subscripts, thereby changing the integral limits and making the formula incorrect.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Could you , that is if it's not a problem, type out what you think it should be? I would greatly appreciate it. Because this is very confusing as to what this method of solving these equations is trying to say..